# How to add two 8 byte numbers stored in byte[] array

Tags: java, arrays

If the byte value increase as 0-127, then -128 to 0 and then the next significant bit is incremented. How can I add two 8 byte numbers?

```
5824 samples =  0 0 0 0 0 0 22 -64
6272 samples =  0 0 0 0 0 0 24 -128
-----------------------------------
12096 samples = 0 0 0 0 0 0 47 64

5824 samples + 6272 samples = 12096 samples
```

I am incrementing the byte array using this code:

```
public static byte[] byteIncrement(byte[] array) {
    byte[] r = array.clone();
    for ( int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) { // LSB to MSB
        byte x = array[ i ];
        if ( x == -1 )
            continue;
        r[ i ] = (byte) (x + 1);
        Arrays.fill( r, i + 1, array.length, (byte) 0 );
        return r;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException( Arrays.toString( array ) );
}
```

For example when I increment this byte array 5284 times I get value given above of 5824 samples:

```
 byte[] array = {(byte) (0), (byte) (0), (byte) (0), (byte) (0), (byte) (0), (byte) (0), (byte) (0), (byte) (0)};
 byte[] incrementedarray = byteIncrement(array);
 for(int k=1;k<=5823;k++) { // 5824 samples for 1st page
        incrementedarray = byteIncrement(incrementedarray);
 }
```

So my question is, how to add such 8 byte (64 bit) numbers in the manner described above. I am using byte arrays because the granule position in an OGG audio bit stream is stored in this way. I am trying to combine two bit streams for which I have to do such addition.

Comment: Why not just use `long`s instead of arrays of 8 `byte`s?

Comment: Or convert the byte array to long, do the add, and convert it back, if you really must have these byte arrays.

Comment: I have encoded data which is stored in byte arrays like above. Is there a way to convert to long, do the operation and then convert back?

Comment: The final byte in the result should be 64.

Comment: @EJP Not sure how you're getting those numbers.

Comment: @EJP I was talking about the result (12096).

Comment: @shmosel Ahhhhhhhhhhhhh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code makes no sense whatsoever. If you must do it longhand, you need to deal with the carry:

```
public static byte[] byteIncrement(byte[] array) {
    byte[] r = array.clone();
    int carry = 1; // as we are incrementing
    for ( int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) { // LSB to MSB
        int sum = (array[i] & 0xff)+carry;
        r[i] = (byte) sum;
        carry = sum >>> 8;
    }
    return r;
}
```

If you want to *add* two of these byte arrays *together*:

```
public static byte[] add(byte[] array1, byte[] array2) {
    byte[] r = new byte[array1.length]; // assuming both arrays are same length
    int carry = 0;
    for ( int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) { // LSB to MSB
        int sum = (array1[i] & 0xff)+(array2[i] & 0xff)+carry;
        r[i] = (byte) sum;
        carry = sum >>> 8;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Errors & omissions excepted.

Comment: Doesn't this method needs to have two arguments passed to it?

Comment: Two arguments such as what? It's your method signature. I didn't change it.

Comment: My method is for incrementing a single byte array. I need a method to add together two byte arrays.

Comment: Well your incrementing method doesn't work either, that's what I answered originally. Otherwise I have no idea why you posted it. I've now added the add method.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `BigInteger` to handle the math:

```
public static byte[] add(byte[] arr1, byte[] arr2) {
    return new BigInteger(arr1).add(new BigInteger(arr2)).toByteArray();
}
```

If the result needs to be a specific size, you can copy it to a new array with the target size:

```
private static byte[] leftPad(byte[] arr, int size) {
    if (arr.length < size) {
        byte[] padded = new byte[size];
        System.arraycopy(arr, 0, padded, size - arr.length, arr.length);
        return padded;
    }
    return arr;
}
```